# When is the ideal time to store user session data for e-commerce platforms such as products viewed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dom-events, e-commerce, service-worker

We have a an ecommerce platform where we need to store user session data in a database such as products viewed and products liked. When is the right time to call an API to store this data?

I don't want to call an API every time they open a new product.

I've experimented with DOM methods such as visibilitychange but on our website, every product is opened in a new tab so it's not ideal.

Should we use some background scripts such as service workers?

Comment: Because Ajax API calls are all asynchronous, there's no need for a service worker.  You can just fire off an Ajax API call to the server anytime you want to have it record something and that costs the client no real CPU time or resources.  So, the question is more about what exactly you want to record, how often those things happen and are there client opportunities to coalesce a few events into one API call for server efficiency reasons or does that risk losing the data if the window/tab is just closed too soon before you've sent the data to the server?

Comment: So, your question, as stated does not really offer enough information to know how to answer.  The only answer given the info you've provided is "it depends" upon lots of information you have not provided.

Comment: FYI, if viewing a product opens a new tab or loads a new page in the existing tab, then the server should just record the view itself.  It knows or could know who the user is making the request (from a cookie) and it knows the product that was just requested from what's in the content of the page that was just served.  It doesn't need any client help in order to record that information.  It can just record it on its own.